# Django - how to create multiple select (on CreateView) to a foreign key on the related model?

Tags: django, forms, view, model, foreign-keys

I have those two models:

### Student

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    class = models.ForeignKey(Class, related_name='students', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

### Class

```
class Class(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True,verbose_name='Code', max_length=50)
```

When the user creates a new Class, I need them to be able to choose the students that it's going to be in the class. And they should be able to add students later. How would I create this view?

Answer (score 0):

try this it mean class can have many student

```
class Class(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True,verbose_name='Code', max_length=50)
    models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```